# How do i set active account for my spfx webpart

Tags: axios, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, web-parts, spfx

I am building an spfx webpart using react to fetch users data in my organization using microsoft graph api below is my code, after making the call an checking the dev console i get this error

> Error fetching user data: Error: No user account

My code:

```
 public getEmp = async (): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
      if (accounts.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("No user account found");
      }
      const activeAccount = accounts[0];
      const request = {
        scopes: ["User.Read"],
        account: activeAccount,
      };
      // msalInstance.setActiveAccount(msalInstance.getActiveAccount());
      const response: AuthenticationResult =
        await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request);

      const accessToken: string = response.accessToken;
      const graphApiResponse = await axios.get(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users",
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
        }
      );
      if (graphApiResponse.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error(
          `Graph API request failed: ${graphApiResponse.statusText}`
        );
      }
      const userData = await graphApiResponse.data;

      console.log("User data:", userData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
    }
  };
```

Please what am i doing wrong? and if there is another away of going about it kindly let me know.

Fetch all users in my organization data

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and mine was solved with below code.

```
 const loginRequest = {
        scopes: ["User.Read"]
      };
if (accounts.length === 0) {
        await msalInstance.ssoSilent(loginRequest);
      }
```